# How to dynamically alter field mapping in django restframework's serializer that uses nested serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use the following serializer in most `requests` such as `GET`, `POST` etc:

```
class PrescriptionSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer()
    setting = SettingSerializer()
```

But, I want to map `setting` field to `SettingUpdateSerializer()` `if request.action` is `UPDATE`(=`PUT/PATCH`). Without diving `PrescriptionGetSerializer` and `PrescriptionUpdateSerialzer` and using them accordingly, is there a way to dynamically map serializer-nesting field to other serializer, as below?

```
class PrescriptionSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer()
    setting = SettingUpdateSerializer()
```

I though about using `self.fields.pop` on `__init__`, but this way it is only possible by using different different field names such as `update_setting` and `get_setting`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most clear solution is creating two separate serializer. And chose what serializer to use in a view layer depends on the http verb. If you use viewset it is easy to implement in a `get_serializer_class` method.

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewset):  

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action === 'update':
            return UpdatePrescriptionSerializer
        return PrescriptionSerializer
```

Now when you'll call a `get_serializer` in actions methods you'll get serializer depends on the action.
But you could also do something like you said:

```
class PrescriptionSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(PrescriptionSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'PUT':
            self.fields['setting'] = SettingUpdateSerializer()
        else:
            self.fields['setting'] = SettingSerializer()

    tags = TagSerializer()
```

Just ensure that you pass a request to serializer context. If you use `get_serializer` method in a viewset then it is already passed.

Comment: dude, you're a life saver. I can't believe I didn't think about `self.fields['setting'] = SettingUpdateSerializer()`. I will try using the `get_serializer_class` if similar situation arises. I have too much legacy code to bother rewriting the whole thing again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bossam no problem, I'm glad it helped you :)